# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in NSString stringWithFormat?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I write some code to get a string in format that i want in ARC and I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2 address=0x100).

Here' the code:

```
NSString *inCook = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GETAFREE_AUTH_HASH=%@; GETAFREE_USER_ID=%@", FRLAuthHash, FRLUserID];
NSLog(@"%@",inCook);

NSString *cookie1 = [[NSString alloc]init]; 
cookie1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"__utma=138759908.342110698.1339513728.1347619146.1347628547.51; __utmz=138759908.1339513728.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); __atuvc=0%7C33%2C0%7C34%2C0%7C35%2C16%7C36%2C50%7C37; GETAFREE_REFERRAL_URL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.freelancer.com%2Fusers%2Fonlogin.php; _chartbeat2=skcgjvrzgugx7kr0.1339513733066.1347628548930.00000000000001; WRUID=0; session2=6d909115a69f37ff641d798045d6f252; __qca=P0-624434954-1344332147605; FL_DASHBOARD_VIEWPAGE_4164248=sellerview; FL_DASHBOARD_TABINDEX_4164248=6; GETAFREE_LANGUAGE=en; __utmc=138759908; __utmb=138759908.1.10.1347628547; SpryMedia_DataTables_project_table_=%7B%22iCreate%22%3A1347628548100%2C%22iStart%22%3A0%2C%22iEnd%22%3A0%2C%22iLength%22%3A10%2C%22sFilter%22%3A%22%22%2C%22sFilterEsc%22%3Atrue%2C%22aaSorting%22%3A%5B%20%5B7%2C%22desc%22%5D%5D%2C%22aaSearchCols%22%3A%5B%20%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%5D%2C%22abVisCols%22%3A%5B%20false%2Ctrue%2Cfalse%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%2Ctrue%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%5D%7D"];

NSString *cookie2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@; %@",cookie1,inCook];

NSLog(@"%@",cookie2);
```

I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS on this line:

```
    cookie1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"__utma=138759908.342110698.1339513728.1347619146.1347628547.51; __utmz=138759908.1339513728.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); __atuvc=0%7C33%2C0%7C34%2C0%7C35%2C16%7C36%2C50%7C37; GETAFREE_REFERRAL_URL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.freelancer.com%2Fusers%2Fonlogin.php; _chartbeat2=skcgjvrzgugx7kr0.1339513733066.1347628548930.00000000000001; WRUID=0; session2=6d909115a69f37ff641d798045d6f252; __qca=P0-624434954-1344332147605; FL_DASHBOARD_VIEWPAGE_4164248=sellerview; FL_DASHBOARD_TABINDEX_4164248=6; GETAFREE_LANGUAGE=en; __utmc=138759908; __utmb=138759908.1.10.1347628547; SpryMedia_DataTables_project_table_=%7B%22iCreate%22%3A1347628548100%2C%22iStart%22%3A0%2C%22iEnd%22%3A0%2C%22iLength%22%3A10%2C%22sFilter%22%3A%22%22%2C%22sFilterEsc%22%3Atrue%2C%22aaSorting%22%3A%5B%20%5B7%2C%22desc%22%5D%5D%2C%22aaSearchCols%22%3A%5B%20%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%5D%2C%22abVisCols%22%3A%5B%20false%2Ctrue%2Cfalse%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%2Ctrue%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%5D%7D"];
```

Value inside is just copy and paste from what i capture from website.

Can anyone tell what did i do wrong?

Many Thanks

Comment: The below answer is correct, but additionally you don't need the lines `NSString *cookie1...` and `cookie1 = [NSString...` you could replace them with `NSString *cookie1 = @"__utma=138759908.3421106....";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the line

```
cookie1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"__utma=138759908.342110698.1339513728.1347619146.1347628547.51; __utmz=138759908.1339513728.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); __atuvc=0%7C33%2C0%7C34%2C0%7C35%2C16%7C36%2C50%7C37; GETAFREE_REFERRAL_URL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.freelancer.com%2Fusers%2Fonlogin.php; _chartbeat2=skcgjvrzgugx7kr0.1339513733066.1347628548930.00000000000001; WRUID=0; session2=6d909115a69f37ff641d798045d6f252; __qca=P0-624434954-1344332147605; FL_DASHBOARD_VIEWPAGE_4164248=sellerview; FL_DASHBOARD_TABINDEX_4164248=6; GETAFREE_LANGUAGE=en; __utmc=138759908; __utmb=138759908.1.10.1347628547; SpryMedia_DataTables_project_table_=%7B%22iCreate%22%3A1347628548100%2C%22iStart%22%3A0%2C%22iEnd%22%3A0%2C%22iLength%22%3A10%2C%22sFilter%22%3A%22%22%2C%22sFilterEsc%22%3Atrue%2C%22aaSorting%22%3A%5B%20%5B7%2C%22desc%22%5D%5D%2C%22aaSearchCols%22%3A%5B%20%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%5D%2C%22abVisCols%22%3A%5B%20false%2Ctrue%2Cfalse%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%2Ctrue%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%5D%7D"];
```

You're asking for a formatted string, and '%' is a [format specifier](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265).
In other words, `-stringWithFormat` needs double-`%` (like `%%`) to make a single percent in the resulting string. Otherwise, it expects you to use one of the Specifiers from the link above.

Did you mean to simply assign the string instead, such as?

```
cookie1 = @"__utma=138759908.342110698.1339513728.1347619146.1347628547.51; __utmz=138759908.1339513728.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); __atuvc=0%7C33%2C0%7C34%2C0%7C35%2C16%7C36%2C50%7C37; GETAFREE_REFERRAL_URL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.freelancer.com%2Fusers%2Fonlogin.php; _chartbeat2=skcgjvrzgugx7kr0.1339513733066.1347628548930.00000000000001; WRUID=0; session2=6d909115a69f37ff641d798045d6f252; __qca=P0-624434954-1344332147605; FL_DASHBOARD_VIEWPAGE_4164248=sellerview; FL_DASHBOARD_TABINDEX_4164248=6; GETAFREE_LANGUAGE=en; __utmc=138759908; __utmb=138759908.1.10.1347628547; SpryMedia_DataTables_project_table_=%7B%22iCreate%22%3A1347628548100%2C%22iStart%22%3A0%2C%22iEnd%22%3A0%2C%22iLength%22%3A10%2C%22sFilter%22%3A%22%22%2C%22sFilterEsc%22%3Atrue%2C%22aaSorting%22%3A%5B%20%5B7%2C%22desc%22%5D%5D%2C%22aaSearchCols%22%3A%5B%20%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B%22%22%2Ctrue%5D%5D%2C%22abVisCols%22%3A%5B%20false%2Ctrue%2Cfalse%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Ctrue%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%2Ctrue%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%2Cfalse%5D%7D";
```

Answer (score 3):

That über-long string of gobbledy-gook has a whole slew of unescaped `%` characters in it.  If any one of those translates to a format string pattern, it'll try to grab a non-existent parameter from the `stringWithFormat:` call and construct a formatted string.

Don't use `stringWithFormat:`.   Given that it is a static string, just use a bare `@"....gobbledy-gook.....";`.

Answer (score 0):

The `%` symbols in your `cookie1` string are throwing off the parser.  If you want an actual percent sign, use `%%` instead of `%`.

Alternatively: since you're not putting anything else into that string, you could also use the `stringWithString` method instead of `stringWithFormat`.  Or simply `@"your cookie"`.